# What is the fastest way to compute a random 64bit neighbor with given hamming-distance of 2 and same hammingweight?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, hamming-distance, hammingweight

Regardless of similar questions already answered here, I want to know the following:

- What is the *fastest way* to compute a **random** 64bit **neighbor** with
  given *hamming-distance of 2* and *same hammingweight*?

I have come up with the following somewhat naive implementation. How can I do (much) better, given I am using MSVC on a Core i7 machine?

- Example:

randomNeighbor called with

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000010111101011110011000111010111

could e.g. result in

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000010111101011110011001110010111

i.e., hamming-distance is 2.

```
int msb = 36;  // msb
int hw = 19;   // hammingweight

long long randomNeighbor(long long number) {
    long long neighbor = number;

    int setBitCnt = 0;
    int unsetBitCnt = 0;

    int setBitNr = rnd(hw - 1);
    int unsetBitNr = rnd(msb - hw - 1);

    bool setBit = true;
    bool unsetBit = true;

    for (int x = 0; setBit && unsetBit && x < msb; x++)
    {
        if (_bittest64(&neighbor, x))
        {
            if (setBitCnt == setBitNr)
            {
                _bittestandreset64(&neighbor, x);
            }
            setBitCnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (unsetBitCnt == unsetBitNr)
            {
                _bittestandset64(&neighbor, x);
            }
            unsetBitCnt++;
        }
    }
    return neighbor;
}
```

Comment: I am especially interested in the case where the hamming-distance is 2.

Comment: Is `pdep` available on your machine?

Comment: Yes, pdep is available. How can I make use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `pdep` you can easily "count down" the 0's or 1's until you're in the position that has been randomly generated. Without actually counting anything, of course.

Using `1ull << pos` as the source and `x` (the old number) as mask, `_pdep_u64(1ull << unsetPos, x)` puts the 1-bit at the `unsetPos`-th 1 in `x`.

Similarly, `_pdep_u64(1ull << setPos, ~x)` puts the 1-bit at the `setPos`-th zero in `x`.

Just XOR those with `x`, obviously.

Comment: Was just looking at that myself. My variation was to pick a 1-clearing-bitset and 0-setting-bitset and xor both with the original value to get. I'm pretty sure that making each bitset can be done in one single-pdep operation. Instead of 1<<pos, just need to pick a number with a (random) bit set for each 2-step in hamming distance needed (and fewer bits than the number of 0's and 1's).

Comment: @wuggy I don't really follow, could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: Sure. As in your usage, if we want a mask that 'clears' just one of the set bits, we can use `_pdep_u64(1<<rand(num_setbits), x)` to get it. If we wanted a bigger distance then instead of `1<<rand(num_setbits)` we can pick a random value from the permutations of `k set bits in num_setbits` (i.e. from the set 1<<rnd | 1<<rnd | 1<<rnd... excluding the overlaps). It might not be faster overall though than using 1<<rand in a loop... picking one of the permutations quickly is trickier than I thought...

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way that comes to mind for 'middle' cases where there are lots of possible neighbours is the following:

1. Assign `x` the starting value `o`
2. Rotate `x` a random amount `r1`
3. Reset the lowest set bit in `x`
4. Rotate `x` a random amount `r2`
5. Set the lowest clear bit in `x`
6. Rotate `x` the other way `r1+r2` places
7. Measure the hamming distance between `x` and `o` (count the bits in `x xor o`). If we've not yet reached the distance we want, go back to 2.

On the positive side, for 'many' cases this should be pretty fast. Every step maps very closely to a single instruction in the newly added [bit manipulation instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets)... and even without those are fairly trivial bit operations (i.e. `x = (x | (x+1))`). (Incidentally, doing this on an ARM processor is probably very close to one-instruction per step...)

There are some serious negatives though:

- This will only work well for numbers with a hamming weight in the middle of the range. It works 'best' when the original has a hamming weight of about 32, and close to the 'edges' (say 0-8 set bits and 56-64 set bits) it may have a hard time finding a valid candidate... and at the very edges it will churn away trying to find a candidate without ever being able to reach it.
- The distribution of neighbours it will find for some number will be complicatedly skewed. It will have a tendency to prefer 'clearing' the first of a sequence of ones and 'set' the first of a sequence of zeros.

If you need a uniform likelihood of producing each possible neighbour, or are operating with numbers with most bits set or clear, then there are still a few ways that come to mind but they're unlikely to be as fast as this in the 'average' case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to bit manipulation instructions. As you have said, your answer has some serious negatives; especially, as I need a uniform likelihood of neighbor distribution.